# Integration Service: How do I change the structure of a SQL Server table in a Data Flow task?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I work with an **Integration Service project in Visual Studio**.

What I want to do is to create a package that reads data from `SourceTable` in a remote database, do some transformation on the data and read it into `DestinationTable` in another database. 
This I know how to do, but my issue is that before I do the transformation on the data, I want to remove a lot of rows from the table.
This SELECT beneath would pick only the rows that I want:

```
FROM (
SELECT  
    PatientID,
    PatientName,
    PatientAddress,
    PatientPostalNumber,
    PatientCity,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PatientID ORDER BY PatientName DESC) rn
    FROM SourceTable
) a
WHERE rn = 1
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the Data Flow Task. That allows you to move data between sources and sinks.

You're likely going to want to create an OLE DB connection to your source and destination databases.

Add a Data Flow task to your package. Double click on it.

Add an OLE DB Source component to the data flow. Double click on it.

In the resulting window, select the OLE DB Connection manager that points to the SourceTable database.

Change the Data Access Mode to SQL Command and then use your query.

At this point, the package will only pull in the data you specified and not the entire `SourceTable`

Add an OLE DB Destination. Use the OLE DB Connection Manager that points to DestinationTable database and select DestinationTable as the table. Click the Columns tab and ensure the columns map as expected.

### Fixing the query

The supplied query is missing the select, but it looks like you were attempting to find all the lowest PatientName within a PatientID. If you find your approach doesn't scale well, a correlated subquery, while it might take an extra moment to write, has generally given me better results than the rownumber approach

```
SELECT  
PatientID,
PatientName,
PatientAddress,
PatientPostalNumber,
PatientCity,
FROM SourceTable AS ST
WHERE
    ST.PatientName =
(
    SELECT MAX(STI.PatientName)
    FROM SourceTable AS STI
    WHERE STI.PatientID = ST.PatientID
);
```

That simply says give me all the rows in SourceTable where the PatientName is the largest for matching PatientIDs